# Utility type to retrieve an array as union

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to type the returnvalue as a union of elements of an array, that is being passed as an argument.

For example, this function returns one of the elements of the array:

```js
type GetValue = <T extends string[]>(values: T, predicate: (v) => boolean) => HOWTOTYPETHIS
```

This function is being used as:

```js
const foundValue = getValue(['a', 'b', 'c'], x => x ==='a')
// type of foundValue must be `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`
```

Answer (score 0):

## Updated answer

As per [vera's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75020190/431967) answer, we can use variadic tuples for the argument `values`.

You can retrieve the values of `T extends string[]` by using `T[number]`, and use variadic tuples `values: [...T]` for the argument.

The type becomes

```js
type GetValue = <T extends readonly string[]>(
  values: [...T], 
  predicate: (v) => boolean
) => T[number]

const foundValue = getValue(['a', 'b', 'c'], x => x ==='a')
// foundValue: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

Playground [link with variadic tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDUCGAbArtAvFAPAFSggA9gIA7AEwGcoAnCJCgezJRCiuFoEsyBzANoBdAHwAKAG6oMVAFxQBAOmV4hAGihh6FbgGMkpeZPl4BZNAFsARhFpCAlFEwioVpkxQMyj51FPnrWyEAKGDdFk4oPnhkdAh5OERpLChJZKoNLQgdfVIfFwBvYKgocLJIgDMmNEpYjCcoKTiqRQreCjEsnIMIewBuYqhuCtSAQiqaijreqCKSkoB6BagAd2gyCGyoYCY6eDRaMkIiXQgwYFWAC3Jt6-oAchoyXab6icpBxeWmWlvoemAByOr2gTBGiWmpSQRxsUAABv5LDY7FAAD5QSYQNobChwz63WhMFZQDbEgCitEJtDE93u9kGAF9BgCgVB3lNkgMmWEIhcqGhdKcqFRpvJ7kh7mioPcrJL0fddJLsNEknExAJxfcNDKtdLFeooEQnC4jZgzdKJfSgA)

#### Old answer

You can retrieve the values of `T extends string[]` by using `T[number]`

Furthermore you can make them final by using `readonly` keyword. This is similar to using `as const`.

The type becomes

```js
type GetValue = <T extends readonly string[]>(
  values: T, 
  predicate: (v) => boolean
) => T[number]
```

Unfortunately, you need to type the array that you pass using `as const`. It's not inferred as being a final.

```js
const foundValue = getValue(['a', 'b', 'c'] as const, x => x ==='a')
// foundValue: 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

Here is a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDUCGAbArtAvFAPAFSggA9gIA7AEwGcoAnCJCgezJRCiuFoEsyBzANoBdAHwAKAG6oMVAFxQ8AGihh6FbgGMkpeZPl4BZNAFsARhFpCAlFEwioppkxQMyNuwsMnzlgFC%20NFk4oPnhkdAh5OERpLChJWKplVQh1LVJ3ewBvXygoQLJggDMmNEpwjFsoKQiqADoi3goxFLTtCCsAblyobiL4gEISsooKjqgcvLyAemmoAHdoMghUqGAmOng0WjJCIg0IMGAFgAtyNbP6AHIaMg2ayuHKHpm5ploL6Hpgbd2H6CY-WiY3ySF25igAAMDEYzBYhFAAD5QEYQRrLCiQl4XWhMeZQZb4gCitFxtDEVyuVh6AF8et9flAnqNYt06b5ZgABYBUAC0xEgGmA-NJ7wCQWORSQ3BQvD4Y3kVyQVyRUCuphVyKuGhV2FCMQiYgESquynVprVOqEyiItnstswjrVyup4sKxyoaA0ByoVAVzs1ao1qu1upCYViRpNZo1ZqtUCQNAKnBtdqgDqdJupQA)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the need for `as const` in your solution, use variadic tuples:

```
type GetValue = <T extends readonly string[]>(values: [...T], predicate: (v: T[number]) => boolean) => T[number]
//                                                    ^^^^^^
```

Arguments will now be inferred literally without requiring `as const`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwDUCGAbArtAvFAPAFSggA9gIA7AEwGcoAnCJCgezJRCiuFoEsyBzANoBdAHwAKAG6oMVAFxQBAOmV4hAGihh6FbgGMkpeZPl4BZNAFsARhFpCAlFEwioVpkxQMyj51FPnrWyEAKGDdFk4oPnhkdAh5OERpLChJZKoNLQgdfVIfFwBvYKgocLJIgDMmNEpYjCcoKTiqRQreCjEsnIMIewBuYqhuCtSAQiqaijreqCKSkoB6BagAd2gyCGyoYCY6eDRaMkIiXQgwYFWAC3Jt6-oAchoyXab6icpBxeWmWlvoemAByOr2gTBGiWmpSQRxsUAABv5LDY7FAAD5QSYQNobChwz63WhMFZQDbEgCitEJtDE93u9kGAF9BgCgVB3lNkgMmWEIhcqGhdKcqFRpvJ7kh7mioPcrJL0fddJLsNEknExAJxfcNDKtdLFeooEQnC4jZgzdKJfSgA)

Comment: Awesome! This was what I was looking for. I played with `T as const` but that is not allowed ([yet?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38968))

Answer (score 0):

To get a union of the types of the values of a tuple or array type, you use `ArrayType[number]`.
For example:

```js
type MyArray = string[]
type t1 = MyArray[number]
//   ^? string

type MyTuple = [number, string]
type t2 = MyTuple[number]
//   ^? string | number
```

So for your case, you can use this:

```js
type GetValue = <T extends string[]>(values: [...T], predicate: (v) => boolean) => T[number]
```

The return type is now `T[number]`, which is the union you wanted.

The type for the parameter `values` uses a "variadic tuple type" to make TypeScript use the "actual" type of the argument, instead of the wider type `string[]`.

If the predicate is being called with each element of the array, one by one, you can type its parameter in the same way: `predicate: (v: T[number]) => boolean`.

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W4XDaW)

Some references:

- [Create a Union type from an Array in TypeScript - Bobby Hadz](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-create-union-type-from-array)
- [How to convert an array into string literal union type in TypeScript? - Melvin George](https://melvingeorge.me/blog/convert-array-into-string-literal-union-type-typescript)